# SDL image disappears after 15 seconds

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl

I'm learning SDL and I have a frustrating problem. Code is below.

Even though there is a loop that keeps the program alive, when I load an image and change the x value of the source rect to animate, the image that was loaded disappears after exactly 15 seconds. This does not happen with static images. Only with animations. I'm sure there is a simple thing I'm missing but I cant see it.

```
void update(){
    rect1.x = 62 * int ( (SDL_GetTicks() / 100) % 12); 
    /* 62 is the width of a frame, 12 is the number of frames */
}

void shark(){

    surface = IMG_Load("s1.png");
    if (surface != 0){
        texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer,surface);
            SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
    }

    rect1.y = 0;

    rect1.h = 90;
    rect1.w = 60;

    rect2.x = 0;
    rect2.y = 0;

    rect2.h = rect1.h+30; // enlarging the image
    rect2.w = rect1.w+30;

    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer,texture,&rect1,&rect2);
}

void render(){
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 100, 150);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
}
```

and in main

```
   update();
   shark();
   render();
```

SDL_image header is included, linked, dll exists. Could be the dll is broken?

I left out rest of the program to keep it simple. If this is not enough, I can post the whole thing.

Comment: At least show your whole loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you call the `shark` function, it loads another copy of the texture. With that in a loop like you have it, you will run out of video memory quickly (unless you are calling `SDL_DestroyTexture` after every frame, which you have not indicated). At which point, you will no longer be able to load textures. Apparently this takes about fifteen seconds for you.

If you're going to use the same image over and over, then just load it once, before your main loop.

Comment: Thanks, adding a destroy function solved it !! I cant see why it doesnt just overwrite the variable though..

Comment: @DanaaMograine: It does overwrite the variable. But the variable, in this case, is just a pointer. Overwriting a pointer has no effect on the thing it points to (a texture, in this case), because there may be other pointers holding that same address.

Comment: So the function CreateTextureFromSurface returns a SDL_Texture on the heap and each time the parent function runs, it has a different adress?

Comment: @DanaaMograine: Something like that, although it doesn't return the `SDL_Texture`, just a pointer to it. And yes, this pointer will store a different address each time, because it is pointing to a different, newly allocated  `SDL_Texture`.

Answer (score 0):

This line int ( (SDL_GetTicks() / 100) % 12);

SDL_GetTicks() returns the number of miliseconds that have elapsed since the lib initialized (https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetTicks). So you're updating with the TOTAL AMOUNT OF TIME since your application started, not the time since last frame.

You're supposed to keep count of the last time and update the application with how much time has passed since the last update.

```
Uint32 currentTime=SDL_GetTicks();
int deltaTime = (int)( currentTime-lastTime );
lastTime=currentTime; //declared previously

update( deltaTime );
shark();
render();
```

Edit: Benjamin is right, the update line works fine.
Still using the deltaTime is a good advice. In a game, for instance, you won't use the total time since the beginning of the application, you'll probably need to keep your own counter of how much time has passed (since you start an animation).

But there's nothing wrong with that line for your program anyhow.

Comment: I see your point but its strange that it stops working after a fixed time.

Comment: Look into Benjamin's answer, it may be a memory problem then.

Comment: *"This will be a random value between 0 and 11, depending on the frame rate."* -- No, it will give a value that depends on the amount of time that has passed. The value will increment every 100 milliseconds, and reset to 0 every 1.2 seconds. The line seems correct to me.